# -How to improve the speed of python query mysql data

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Why do I use database tools to execute SQL quickly, but it takes 15 seconds to execute with pymysql. this data table have over 30 million rows data.Index has been created on car_device field and upload_time.

Here is the python method

```
def get_db_data(time_start, time_end, deviceid):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=str(configDict["gps_database"]["hosts"]), port=configDict["gps_database"]["port"],
                           user=str(configDict["gps_database"]["user"]),
                           passwd=str(configDict["gps_database"]["passwd"]),
                           db=str(configDict["gps_database"]["db"]), charset='utf8')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT id,longitude,latitude,weight,speed,upload_time FROM gps.factual_data where (upload_time between'" + time_start + "' AND '" + time_end + "' AND car_device = " + deviceid + ") order by upload_time asc;"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results_data = cursor.fetchall()
        desc = cursor.description
    except:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return None
    return result
```

SQL here

```
select id,longitude,latitude,speed,weight,upload_time from factual_data where car_device='867032059168612' and upload_time between '2021-05-07 00:00:00' and '2021-05-18 00:00:00' order by upload_time desc
```

Comment: The DB tool only pulls part of the data. Try scrolling down to the end and see if you can do that quickly

Comment: I can scrolling down quickly-Tarik

Comment: Can you reach the bottom quickly, I mean the 30,000,000th row.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express it clearly. What I mean is that there are currently 30 million rows of data in this table, but I only query a part of it, about 60,000 rows. This process takes about 15 seconds when using pymysql to query, but the DB Tool only takes about 1s.

Comment: Please update your question with your Python code, without which we cannot see what may contribute to the low performance.

Comment: Question update ,add python code.

Comment: Just a remark: Use a parameterized query for better security. (Avoiding SQL injection)

Comment: What I told you still holds: SQL tools fetch as you scroll, so it seems faster while in fact it is working in the background. Look at memory, CPU and network utilization while you are running your query from the DB tool.